# UIViewController for login before UITabBarController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to visualize one UIViewController with login request.
After login (if ok) I would like to show my application that is composed by a UITabBarController with various tabs.
Now I usually use in AppDelegate this code to manage UITabBarController:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and this will show my app. How I can show, before this, one UIViewController for login request?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** One way is to make your login controller the root view controller and push the tab bar controller with its view controllers from there. You can check for login during app start and skip right to the tab bar controller without animation.

**2.** Alternatively, you can cover the tab bar controller with an overlay (add a subview to the window). Then display your login controller's view on top of that if need be, or make the overlay disappear immediately.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.... I've resolved in this way... after correct login I call this code:
    homeViewController *controller = [[homeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

            tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller, nil];
            tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            [self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Please don't forget to tick the check mark.